# How to remove 2 quarters before and one quarter after in a quarterly dataset based on a variable whether a quarter is marked 1 or not?

Tags: dataframe, data-cleaning

I have a quarterly dataset for 1000s of firms with 40 variables. I want to remove two quarters before, one quarter after and the quarter if a quarter is marked one in a variable. But, I'm not able to do that. Please help

If the variable IPO is marked 1 in CalendarYearQuarter 5 for a firm with TIC "AAPL", then i want to remove the datapoints of quarters (3,4,5,6).

I tried the code below but it is not working.

```
IPO_value <- 1 

remove_quarters <- function(df) {
  quarters_to_remove <- df %>%
    filter(IPO == IPO_value) %>%
    mutate(
      Quarter_to_remove = CalendarYearQuarter - 2,
      Quarter_to_remove_after = CalendarYearQuarter + 1
    )

  data_dti <- data_dt %>%
    anti_join(quarters_to_remove, by = c("TIC","CalendarYearQuarter"))
```